# Use collision when freeze rigidbody positions

Tags: unity-game-engine

how to use collision when freeze rigidbody positions. When freezed rigidbody positions in game object have not collision.

Answer (score 0):

If you freeze an axis of position or rotation it should work as a static object, you can also click the `Static` checkbox on top of the `Inspector` when selecting the `gameObject` on the `Hierarchy` window.

Check `isKinematic` as false since that way it ignores all physics behaviours.